# Alternatives to MSScriptControl for executing JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, iis, msscriptcontrol

Since msscript.ocx MSScriptControl is 32 bit only, and Microsoft will be deprecating it, what is the alternative?

I am having an issue that MSScriptControl works perfectly so long as I run in a 32 bit application pool.  But since it is a 32 bit control, I can never run in a 64 bit pool since it will crash.

Are there any replacements?

Comment: what kinds of javascript are you running?

Comment: Just some end user scrip-table calculations.

Comment: Why do you even need to run it in a 64bit app pool? Just run it in 32 bit mode.

Comment: @saille well, because we would like to keep the ability to address more than 4gb of memory.  The website is heavy memory user due to caching a lot of data in RAM.  I think i may have to go with a proxy solution.  Have the part that does the javascript proecessing run in a separate website that runs in a 32 bit pool, and the main web app to run in a 64 bit application pool.